# How can i get value from properties with resource jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I have a properties files called `toto.properties` contains these values :

```
SaraTimeout=30000
SaraTargetService=CIST
```

In my class I have :

```
@Resource(name = "SaraTargetService")
private String service;

@Resource(name = "SaraTimeout")
private long timeout;
```

I using jboss as server application, How can i inject the value of `SaraTargetService` and `SaraTimeout` to the String service and long timeout.

The goal is to retrieve values from `toto.properties` ​​and inject variables into class attribute.

thxs

Comment: With CDI you could try and use a producer that reads from the file and delivers what needs to be produced.

Comment: @Thomas Can you give me an example please

Comment: Result of a quick google search: http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/06/inject-java-properties-in-java-ee-using-cdi/

Comment: Is There another way because with Tomee Server, it works by adding @Resource on the specific attribute of the class, may be in Jboss there is the same functionality.

Comment: There probably is but it might depend on the jboss version you're using.

Comment: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21)

Comment: No idea about JBoss 7.5 (we're only using the community edition) so I can't really tell you. I'd prefer the CDI approach anyways since it's vendor independent and more flexible but have a look here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Development_Guide/Enable_EJB_and_MDB_Property_Substitution_in_an_Application.html - as an example this states you need to enable property substitution